# Accessing Azure Resource properties from logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is there a simple way for a logic app to access its own Azure service management properties? Ideally I want to be able to access the location where the logic app is deployed.

The only current solution I have found is to make a rest call to the Azure service management API and get the details for using the logic app resource ID. However, this requires co-administrator privileges.

There feels like there should be an easier way for a resource to just access its own properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @workflow().location expression to get the location of the Logic App.